# Fast C++ library for stereo vision/disparity computation

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

I am looking for a library for disparity map / stereo vision computation. These are my requirements:

1. C++
2. Multi-platform (Linux, Windows, OSX)
3. (preferrable but not mandatory) not CUDA based
4. Suited for robotics (e.g. it should work even if the images are not perfectly rectified and the cameras are not perfectly calibrated)
5. Suitable for tracking purposes (20fps or more)
6. Performing even with low-res images (e.g. 320x240px)
7. Open Source

Comment: Have you looked at OpenCV?

Comment: Yes. OpenCV was our first choice but it falls short mainly because of item #4. Further, it is very slow (running at 1fps with images at 640x480px even on powerful machines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer this question on my own, but feel free to add more information on that.

We tried OpenCV's standard disparity function, but it fell short mainly because of item #4. Further, it is very slow (running at 1fps with images at 640x480px even on powerful machines).

Recently, we are doing some tests with [**libelas**](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libelas) and it seems promising. It is more robust, faster and it generally works better.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned about [libviso](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso/).  I didn't compare to all of your requirements, but it looks pretty good.

Comment: Both **libelas** and **libviso** libraries are from the same author; the former deals with the disparity, whereas the latter with the visual odometry.